# react native getting width and height using Image getSize()

Tags: react-native

I used Image.getSize() for resizing the uri image.

**In the case of iOS**, the correct image size value was obtained,

But **In the case of android**, the large image size is output with a small value although the ratio are correct.

ios : 1)900 7350 2)900 7350 3)900 5800 4)1000 1066 5)900 1086

android : 1)225 1838 2)225 1838 3)225 1450 4)1000 1066 5)900 1086

What should I do?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? In case of iOS what does happen?

Comment: For ios, get the exact image size.